# Cannot write to HID USB device (Arduino, V-USB, HidSharp)

Tags: usb, avr

I am currently prototyping an HID USB device using Arduino Nano and V-USB library. The problem is that although I can read from the device I cannot write to it.
Here is the schema:
[image: Schema]
As for the firmware I'm using the [hid-serial](https://github.com/rayshobby/hid-serial) library.
Here is the Arduino code:

```
#include <HIDSerial.h>

HIDSerial serial;

unsigned char buffer[32];

void setup() {
  serial.begin();
}

void loop() {
  if(serial.available()) {
    int size = serial.read(buffer);
    if (size!=0) {
      serial.write((const uint8_t*)buffer, size);
      serial.write('\n');
    }
  }
  serial.poll();
}
```

Here is the HID report descriptor:

```
    0x06, 0x00, 0xff,              // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x01,                    // USAGE (Vendor Usage 1)
    0xa1, 0x01,                    // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x15, 0x00,                    //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x26, 0xff, 0x00,              //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (255)
    0x75, 0x08,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x95, 0x08,                    //   REPORT_COUNT (8)
    0x09, 0x00,                    //   USAGE (Undefined)  
    0x82, 0x02, 0x01,              //   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs,Buf)
    0x95, HIDSERIAL_INBUFFER_SIZE, //   REPORT_COUNT (32)
    0x09, 0x00,                    //   USAGE (Undefined)        
    0xb2, 0x02, 0x01,              //   FEATURE (Data,Var,Abs,Buf)
    0xc0                           // END_COLLECTION
```

And lastly, here is the code running on host (.NET/C# using HidSharp library):

```
var devices = DeviceList.Local;
var hidDeviceCollection = devices.GetHidDevices(this.vendorId, this.productId).ToList();
var device = hidDeviceCollection.First();
var stream = device.Open();
var buffer = new byte[9];
buffer[0] = 0;
buffer[1] = 42;
stream.Write(buffer);
buffer = stream.Read();
```

When I run the code above despite stream.CanRead being true I receive an exception "Can't write to this device.". However if I change the code to the "Hello World" example provided by the library I can read from the device without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error.
While the HidSharp was sending output reports, the device driver expected feature reports.
Changing the line

```
0xb2, 0x02, 0x01,              //   FEATURE (Data,Var,Abs,Buf)
```

to

```
0x92, 0x02, 0x01,              //   OUTPUT (Data,Var,Abs,Buf)
```

resolved the issue.